# xfire: Intercepting Webservice header information

Tags: java, security, web-services, xfire

I have some webservices exposed through xfire and want to have security around those webservice calls. How can I add security without changing anything inside the web services? Basically I want to intercept these webservice calls before it is reaching actual webservice and to authenticate those calls. Please help me

Regards
Vishal G

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/). It can provide security around an existing non-Spring application without any internal modification.